# Is it possible to always show the action buttons on iOS10 notifications?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

With the new iOS10 notifications, is there a way to have action buttons always displayed without having the user swiping / force touching the notification for them to appear below the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As before, the system controls the notifications UI and you have no control over it. Even if users set the notification style to "Alerts", the actions still will not appear unless the user interacts with the notification.